# SAS: How to create datasets in loop based on macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro variable like this:

```
%let months = 202002 202001 201912 201911 201910;
```

As one can see, we have 5 months, separated by space ' '.

I would like to create 5 datasets like `a_202002, a_202001, a_201912, a_2019_11, a_201910`. How can I run this in loop and create 5 datasets, instead of writing the datastep 5 times?

Pseudo code:

```
for m in &months.
    data a_m;
        ....
        ....
    run;
```

How can I do that in SAS? I tried [`%do_over`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lecompobjref&docsetTarget=p07odyzmifa4y3n10pkcvfdbtn4l.htm&docsetVersion=3.1&locale=en) but that did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the knowledge you gained from @Tom answer in an earlier question to create the macro

```
%macro datasets_for_months ...
  ...
%mend;
```

Specify the output data sets in the `DATA` statement:

```
DATA %datasets_for_months(...);
  ...
RUN;
```

Direct rows to specific output data sets by naming the data set, such as

```
  OUTPUT a_202002;
```

Note:

- A step with no OUTPUT statements will implicitly output to each data set
- A step with an `OUTPUT` statement will cause records to be written to either ALL data sets, or only the ones named in the statement:

  - `OUTPUT` writes records to all output data sets
  - `OUTPUT data-set-name-1` writes records to only data sets specified

The [DATA Step](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1kh25to5o0wmvn1o4n4hsl3yyww.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) documentation covers what you need to know in greater detail

> **DATA Statement**
>   Begins a DATA step and provides names for any output such as SAS data sets, views, or programs.
>   ...
>   **Syntax**
>
> **Form 1:**
>   DATA statement for creating output data sets
>
> `DATA <data-set-name-1 <(data-set-options-1)>>`
>    `... <data-set-name-n <(data-set-options-n)>>
>   ... ;`

**THE ROAD AHEAD**

You will likely discover that `month` will be better served in a conceptual role as a categorical variable in a single large data set, instead of breaking the data into multiple *month-named* data sets.

A categorical variable will let you leverage the power of SAS' partitioning and segregating statements such as `WHERE`, `BY` and `CLASS` when pursuing processing, reporting and visualization of your data at different combinations of class level values.

Comment: Actually, using Tom's answer as a template I was trying tho solve this issue. But the problem is that I have to import text files using `infile` statement and, with data of each month lying in month folder like `202002`, `202001` and so on.

Comment: SAS can read from multiple files in one step.  When the files have the same structure, all the data can be easily read into **one** data set using **one** step.

Comment: Echoing Richard, you can read from multiple files or have a data set with filenames that you then read each one with. Are all the files the exact same structure? https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-do-I-write-a-macro-to-import-multiple-text-files-that-have/ta-p/223627

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach? Create the data set names in another macro variable and use a single data step.

```
%let months = 202002 202001 201912 201911 201910;

data _null_;
   ds = prxchange('s/(\d+)/a_$1/', -1, "&months.");
   call symputx('ds', ds);
run;

options symbolgen;
data &ds.;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a %DO loop and the %SCAN() function.  Use the COUNTW() function to find the upper bound.

```
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&months,%str( )));
  %let month=%scan(&months,&i,%str( ));
  ....
%end;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. That's another way.